# What is the best way to send custom ACS Claims across programs?

Tags: c#, azure, claims-based-identity, acs

I've got two programs, a "login" program that uses the a foreign STS (Google, Facebook, etc.) to log the user in and returns the type of security access that user has. I then want to send that information off to a separate program that takes that security access and gives the user privileges based on that.

What is the best way to send that information across?

I've read some things about the Custom Authorization Manager Service, but I'm not sure if that is what I need here. Is it possible to just POST the security info across and the web.config turns that into a claim? Should I be making a new token and sending that?

I am hopelessly lost. If someone could provide a helpful tutorial somewhere on the web, that would be immensely appreciated (as my googling has only turned up long-winded articles that either do much more than I need or much less).

Specific code snippets would make my day.

Thanks!

EDIT: I am trying to avoid making the login system into an STS. But I am starting to feel I need to. Is there some halfway point between STS and relying party? Like a relying party that can generate its own claims?

Comment: Any reason you have this in two different apps?

Comment: Basically, we are trying to separate the login service from the actual bulk of the application for code clarity reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

1. The simplest one is the ClaimsAuthorizationManager, which might be what you're looking for. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748497.aspx The CAM is a step in the ASP.NET authentication pipeline that runs right after your application has validated the security token incoming from ACS. Here is where you define your custom authorization logic, and you can add additional claims to the IClaimsPrincipal that gets delivered to yor application. Instead of centralizing authorization logic in a service, you could for example implement your CAM in a library that's shared accross various relying party applications.
2. If your authorization rules are simple, i.e., you're not querying any external user attribute store, then one option would be to use ACS claims transformation rules to do this. Then your applications would consume the token issued by ACS directly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185955.aspx
3. If however your architecture absolutely requires a separate login service that consumes tokens and populates new tokens with user attributes and such, then it will need to be an STS. Building your own STS can be tricky, but there are prefabricated STSes available to do this. If your applications live in an AD domain for example, ADFS 2.0 would be an ideal choice because of it's close integration with AD and ACS, and it's powerful claims transformation capabilities.